# ng-model not updates inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

The "declineReasonId" variable is not updates. i use $parent to access parent variable inside "ng-repeat" but it still not working.

I have ng-template html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="boxDeclineReasonPopup.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Chose reason</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group reasonPopupLabel">
                <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in reasons" ng-if="key != 0">
                    <label>{{value}}</label>
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="reason" ng-model="$parent.declineReasonId" ng-value="{{key}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="declineReasonId === '0'" ng-click="ok()">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

and my controller:

```
(function () {
    function declineReasonModalController($scope, $modalInstance, appData) {

        $scope.declineReasonId = '0';
        $scope.reasons = appData.report_type;
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.declineReasonId);
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

        $scope.$watch('declineReasonId', function () {
            debugger;
        });
    }

    declineReasonModalController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'appData'];
    var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers');
    controllers.controller('DeclineReasonModalController', declineReasonModalController);
})();
```

The modal instance triggered by function:

```
$scope.decline = function () {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'boxDeclineReasonPopup.html',
                controller: 'DeclineReasonModalController'
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (reasonId) {
                $scope.declineReasonId = reasonId;
                $scope.declineConfirm();
            }, function () { });
        };
```

If i put "{{$parent.declineReasonId }}" inside ng-repeat is duplicate copy of variable. When i press radio button is change value of one of duplicated copies. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$parent` is still not the modal controller's scope yet.

You can use `$parent.$parent.declineReasonId` to reach the scope in your specific case.

That is why the use of `$parent` is discouraged.

The best practice when using `ng-model` is to not reference something in $scope directly, like this:

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.declineReasonId = '0';
```

Then change your `ng-model` this instead:

```
ng-model="model.declineReasonId"
```

Comment: I don't understand what the difference between using a new object named 'model' and a simple variable $scope.declineReasonId. Why are they not in the same scope?